# Comparing individual characters in a string. Finding Consonants in a user input string of letters

Tags: c++, string, compare, cstring

I've been tasked to write code for a c++ program that will find the consonants in user input. So, if I enter abc, the program will tell me that there are two consonants. The question is below. I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me, I just need someone to help me figure out how to compare user input characters to a string.

Write a program that determines how many consonants are in an entered string of 50 characters or less. Output the entered string and the number of consonants in the string. You can assume the following ;
Consonants: bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz

Comment: Create a container containing the consonants. For each character of user input, look in that container to see if the current character is present or not. If it is, add one to your count.

Comment: A good way of checking the container (or simple string) is with `strchr`. Say you have a string `const char *vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";` Your character can be checked as `if (strchr (vowels, c) != NULL)`. There are many ways, but these are a few efficient starters.

Answer (score 0):

Define a string with all consonants:

```
string cons = "bcd" // etc
```

Put your actual sting to lower case, if needed

```
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Next, itearete through your string characters and try to find this character in the consonant string.

```
int consonants = 0;
for (string::iterator i = str.begin(); i !< str.end(); ++i)
   if (cons.find(*i) != string::npos)
      ++consonants;
```

Or, if you are sure that your string will only contains characters from a-z, use vowels as suggested below:

```
 string vow = "aei" // etc
 //...
 int consonants = 0;
 for (string::iterator i = str.begin(); i !< str.end(); ++i)
    if (vow.find(*i) == string::npos)
       ++consonants;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to just create a string with the `vowels`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: If you're sure all the input will be letters, it might be. If input might include things like digits and/or punctuation, it might add more complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient method, but since you're only dealing with strings of less than 50 characters, it's not a big deal.

Here's the pseudocode:

```
Create a string containing all of the consonants as you listed above.
Prompt user for input
Store the input in a string
Use a loop to iterate through each character of the input string
    Use another loop to check each character against your string of consonants
        If it matches a consonant, increment your counter
Output the input string and count
```

If you're using C++ strings, you'll use the string length in your loop stopping condition.
If you're using C strings, you'll use the null byte in your loop stopping condition.